# Given two vectors that form a basis of both the column space and the row space construct its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is: construct a matrix A with $[1, 0, 1]^T$ and $[1, 2, 0]^T$ as a basis for its row space and its column space.

From this I get that it is a 3x3 square matrix with these vectors as rows but I do not know how to cotinue. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: construct a $3\times3$ matrix such that these vectors are both its rows and columns:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
&1 &1\\
1& 2 & 0\\
1 & 0& 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Then fill in the empty element with a number such that the new row/column is linearly dependent on the other rows/colums.

> $$\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\1\\1\end{array}\right)=a\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\0\end{array}\right)+b\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\1\end{array}\right)\implies a= \frac12,\quad b=1\implies x=\frac32$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider this matrix 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Rank of this matrix is $2$. I just tried to make a symmetric matrix with the two vectors you have as basis for the row space.